# JComboBox autocomplete

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

How do I perform auto-complete in editable `JComboBox` in Netbeans 7.1 like in `ComboBox` in VB dot net. I have a combo box with a list binding, I want to select item by typing only some first letter of the item in the list for example if a list has `kitten`, then it should be chosen when I type `ki`.

Answer (score 46):

If you want to do this yourself, you can follow the steps explained in [this article](http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/).

```
this.comboBox = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "Ester", "Jordi",
        "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi" });
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.comboBox);
```

Comment: Don't know how it was when this was written, but the code in the first link is now in public domain and available on the site. It was usable right away.

Comment: second link is changed.

Comment: you wont add library (swingx-all-1.6.4.jar)
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingxall164jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

Another cool library that search through a JComboBox:
http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm

you can download the jar here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jide/jide-oss-3.5.7.jar.zip

After importing the library in your project all you have to do is:

```
JComboBox comboBox = ....;
ComboBoxSearchable searchable = new ComboBoxSearchable(comboBox);
```

Comment: how can i add the `searchable` to a `jpanel`?

Comment: @alex you only don't need to add the combobox to the JPanel. I cannot find the JavaDoc online, so I pasted it here: https://pastebin.com/QnjqLMJr

Answer (score 0):

I developed a custom swing JComboBox named "*AutoComboBox*" which auto completes as you type on it by forking this [gist](https://gist.github.com/resarahadian/5076440).

Here is an small demo.

*First declare and initialize it*. (If you are using an IDE, just drag and place the Class on to your JFrame or JDialog Form)

```
AutoComboBox autoComboBox = new AutoComboBox();
```

*Next, set the item list*. It takes an String array. You may change the type by modifying the AutoComboBox class.

```
String[] itemArray =  {"Malith", "John", "Jack" };
autoComboBox.setKeyWord(itemArray);
```

Now you have an auto completing JComboBox which has "Malith", "John", "Jack" as items !

Here are the two Classes I developed,

**The AutoComboBox.java**

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class AutoComboBox extends JComboBox<Object> {

String keyWord[] = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
Vector myVector = new Vector();

public AutoComboBox() {

    setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(myVector));
    setSelectedIndex(-1);
    setEditable(true);
    JTextField text = (JTextField) this.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    text.setFocusable(true);
    text.setText("");
    text.addKeyListener(new ComboListener(this, myVector));
    setMyVector();
}

/**
 * set the item list of the AutoComboBox
 * @param keyWord an String array
 */
public void setKeyWord(String[] keyWord) {
    this.keyWord = keyWord;
    setMyVectorInitial();
}

private void setMyVector() {
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a < keyWord.length; a++) {
        myVector.add(keyWord[a]);
    }
}

private void setMyVectorInitial() {
    myVector.clear();
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a < keyWord.length; a++) {

        myVector.add(keyWord[a]);
    }
}

}
```

**The ComboListener.java**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

public class ComboListener extends KeyAdapter
{
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
JComboBox cbListener;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Vector vector;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public ComboListener(JComboBox cbListenerParam, Vector vectorParam)
{
    cbListener = cbListenerParam;
    vector = vectorParam;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key)
{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = ((JTextField)key.getSource()).getText();

            cbListener.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(getFilteredList(text)));
            cbListener.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            ((JTextField)cbListener.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setText(text);
            cbListener.showPopup();
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public Vector getFilteredList(String text)
{
    Vector v = new Vector();
    for(int a = 0;a<vector.size();a++)
    {
        if(vector.get(a).toString().startsWith(text))
        {
            v.add(vector.get(a).toString());
        }
                    else if(vector.get(a).toString().startsWith(text.toLowerCase()))
        {
            v.add(vector.get(a).toString());
        }
                     else if(vector.get(a).toString().startsWith(text.toUpperCase()))
        {
            v.add(vector.get(a).toString());
        }
                     else if(vector.get(a).toString().startsWith(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(text)))
        {
            v.add(vector.get(a).toString());
        }
                     else if(vector.get(a).toString().startsWith(WordUtils.uncapitalize(text)))
        {
            v.add(vector.get(a).toString());
        }
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but it needs some changes. Most importantly, the home key doesn't work in your solution. I have fixed that here: http://tinybrain.de/1007529. An open question is how to make the down arrow work properly.