# combo box that is editable having problems

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am using a combo box where values are displayed and i have already checked editable true. I am using netBeans. I have values in the combo box for e.g.

- Apple
- Ant
- Ape
- Bottle
- Bat
- Ball

So when i will type A in the combo box it should display Apple, Ant, Ape in the list. Is there a way to do this?I have use decorate also but it not good.

Comment: Probably you could try adding a key listener to the combobox and filtering the entries accordingly. Could you add some minimal running code so it's easier for us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: There's no default auto-complete functionality. You can look at the links from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13682101/2587435) to see a couple options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto complete combo box in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562131/auto-complete-combo-box-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `JTextField` that does this:

```
int num = 0;
while(true){
if(comboBox.getComponentAt(num).getString().toLowerCase().toCharArray()[0] == JTextField.getText.toLowerCase().toCharArray()[0){

if(num == null){
num == 0;
}
//code to switch current item in JComboBox (sorry, don't know that code)
JTextField.setText("");
num++;

}

    }
```

The user starts typing, and than the program automatically scans the text, and finds if the first letter in the `JTextField` is the same as the label in one of the labels as one of the `JComboBox` items.
Hope this works!