# How to work autocomplete combobox java swing?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I store some names in a database. I want to rework the editable combobox in my netbeans javaform. I want to type the first letter in an editable combobox and then display all names starting with 'a'. I can the choose one of these names. How can I solve this?

Comment: look at sql like keword

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681977/jcombobox-autocomplete