# Java JComboBox with autocomplete

Tags: java, autocomplete, jcombobox, dropdown

i am trying to put a dropdown JComboBox in my application with autocompletion.

I already managed to do the autocompletion part but it only works with the first letters, so if i type "fre" it gives me "Fresas del Pacifico" that is OK

What i need is to be able to type "Paci" and also get "Fresas del Pacifico"

[image: example]

i am using AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBoxCliente);

Any ideas? or 3rd party libs?

thanks

Comment: Where does the AutoCompleteDecorator class come from?

Comment: it comes from SwingX

Answer (score 1):

you can look into

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm

or

http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-jcombobox-autocomplete.html

or

[JComboBox autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681977/jcombobox-autocomplete)

Comment: Those solutions are not what i'm looking for, cause it only autocompletes the text from the begining. I need to be able to "search" the substring at any part of the jcombobox items, not only from the begining