# addKeyListener not recognising text

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a Combobox which is enabled so the user can input text. As they input a letter, an autosuggest/autocomplete should appear. I have the following code but for some reason, it is not working. I believe the issue is `addKeyListener` as that what will make it show the popup.

```
public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

String Pesawat [] = {"Epping","Lion Air","Lufthansa Air","Batavia Air","Bali Air"};

Vector vectorPesawat = new Vector();

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame1
 */
public NewJFrame1() {
    initComponents();        
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(Pesawat) );
    jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(111, 111, 111)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(166, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(58, 58, 58)
            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(222, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jComboBox1.addKeyListener(new ComboListener(jComboBox1,vectorPesawat));

    pack();
```

And the file for `ComboListener` is:

```
public class ComboListener extends KeyAdapter {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JComboBox cbListener;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Vector vector;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public ComboListener(JComboBox cbListenerParam, Vector vectorParam) {
        cbListener = cbListenerParam;
        vector = vectorParam;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = ((JTextField)key.getSource()).getText();
        cbListener.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(getFilteredList(text)));
        cbListener.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        ((JTextField)cbListener.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).setText(text);
        cbListener.showPopup();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Vector getFilteredList(String text) {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        for (int a = 0; a<vector.size(); a++) {
            if (vector.get(a).toString().startsWith(text)) {
                v.add(vector.get(a).toString());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from recommending a DocumentListener over a KeyListener, the listener belongs on the combo box’s editor

Comment: This is something which has been solved a number of times before [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681977/jcombobox-autocomplete)